# Opera box-sizing does not work for textarea with flex

Tags: css, opera, flexbox

I found a bug in Opera: box-sizing does not work for textarea in flex display mode.

```css
b {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

textarea {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
}
```

Here example: http://jsfiddle.net/pJc5v/3/

What to do?

Comment: The bug is what exactly? If box-sizing wasn't working as you claimed, the elements would be in 2 rows no matter what if you enabled wrapping: http://jsfiddle.net/pJc5v/6/

Comment: No-no. Look at this example at chrome and opera.

Div and textarea (in opera) has different height (a bug).

Comment: If there's a bug here, it has nothing to do with box-sizing (http://tinker.io/691f3/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this by using max-height.

http://tinker.io/691f3/2

```
textarea {
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```